# Time/Instructions-wise, is redirecting output to nul the same as not printing?

Tags: windows, c++03

I would like to understand if and what is the difference between redirecting a printed string to NUL, and just not printing it?
Assume the application name is App.exe

```
{
    ...
    cout<< "Testing time/instructions\n";
    ...
}
```

ran with a redirection:

```
App.exe > nul  / or App.exe > nul 2>&1
```

and a code that doesn't have the cout command (we can assume the cout happens inf times so it's easier for me to understand)

The application doesn't know it is being redirected. But is the O.S handling the cout with an instant return "success"? Or is NUL like a temp file that will have effect on the run time?
+ is there a difference between linux/ windows nul handling?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your code is still writing output to a file. It just so happens that the file doesn't work like ordinary files; it throws away everything you write to it.

Comment: So you could say it writes to a temp file -> fseek to the beginning -> repeat? I've run a few tests on windows and the application runs a few seconds faster when redirecting the output than with regular printing.

Comment: Console output is inherently slow on Windows. Redirecting to a file usually buys you a noticeable speedup. Whether that is a real file or NUL doesn't make much of a difference.

Comment: So to sum up, printing to the console is slowest; printing to a file is significantly faster than that; printing to NUL is a little bit faster than that; and not printing is fastest of all.